# How to allow editing of cells within SAPUI5 Table

Tags: sapui5

Can you please show me how to allow editing of cells within SAPUI5 table? I am using JSON model.

Comment: Are you using sap.m.Table or sap.ui.table.Table?

Answer (score 2):

look at this examples in the SDK [Table.html](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html), both of the examples show how to set a json model, set the json model as a data source of a table control, how to bind rows of the json to rows of the table, and how to bind the values to cells, once you change the cells values the new value will be reflect in the model

```
var employeeData = [
  {lastName: "Dente", name: "Al"},
  {lastName: "Friese", name: "Andy"},
  {lastName: "Mann", name: "Anita"},
  {lastName: "Schutt", name: "Doris}
 ];

//create the JSON model and set your data
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({ Employees: employeeData });  

//create table
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();

//add a column for lastname and bind the value to an editable textview
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Last Name"}),
template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "lastName"),
 });

//add a column for name and bind the value to an editable textview
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "First Name"}),
template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "name"),
}));

oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("/Employees);
```

Comment: The above does not answer my question - I need to be able to save my changes? We are using SAP MII Server.

Answer (score 1):

First your table template objects have to be editable. For a textfield either use the `setEditable(true)`, `bindProperty('editable',true)` or directly in the construtor `new TextField({editalbe:true})`.

If it is editable ensure you have switched on two way binding in your model. For JSON models this is the default I think. Also ensure, that there are no formatters involved, because these will destroy two way binding.

The you can check in your debugger, if the changes on the UI are transfered to the model. In general this works fine and from this point it is up to you what to do with the model (send it to some oData save service).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a table that had to be editable when the value was zero and non-editable when it was greater than zero.

Value1 is my dinamic value.
Value2 is zero

```
<Input type="Number" editable="{parts:[{path : 'Value1'}, {path : 'Value2'}], formatter:'sap.ui.app.model.formatter.CantEditable'}"/>
```

Inside the formatter i defined a function called CantEditable like this.

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.app.model.formatter");
 sap.ui.app.model.formatter = 
 {
 function1: (Value1, Value2)
 {
 //If value 1 > Value 2 return editable
 if (Value1>Value2)
 {
 return false;
 }
 else
 {
 return true;
 }
 };
```

Since its binded to the value of these two variables. Whenever my value one changes, the editable function will check if it meets the requeriments of the function. Then it will change the value of the editable property.

Answer (score 0):

My `sap.m.Table` demo here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qifky6plPEzFtlpyV2vb?p=preview

I am using `data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"`, you can change it to `sap_bluecrystal`.

The basic idea is using `editable` property of `sap.m.Input`, and `enabled` property of `sap.m.Select`.

I opened an issue of ui5 to discuss this problem: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1646